# How can I understand which value(s) are null

Tags: c#

```
       public static void ReadExcelFileDOM(string fileName)
        {
            using (SpreadsheetDocument spreadsheetDocument = SpreadsheetDocument.Open(fileName, false))
            {
                WorkbookPart workbookPart = spreadsheetDocument.WorkbookPart;
                WorksheetPart worksheetPart = workbookPart.WorksheetParts.First();
                SheetData sheetData = worksheetPart.Worksheet.Elements<SheetData>().First();
                string text;
                foreach (Row r in sheetData.Elements<Row>())
                {
                    foreach (Cell c in r.Elements<Cell>())
                    {
                        
                        text = c.CellValue.Text;
                        
                        Console.Write(text + " ");
                        
                    }
                }
               
            }
```

Here is my code. When l run it, l am getting the error "c.CellValue.Text is null". That cause some of values returns null when excel file is finish but i do not understand which values are null. Could anyone help me with that?
Thanks a lot.

Comment: Are you paraphrasing the error message, or is that the exact wording of the error?

Comment: System.NullReferenceException:'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'

DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.CellType.CellValue.get returned null.

on "text = c.CellValue.Text;

Comment: [What is a NullReferenceException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: Have you tried using the debugger to see where it fails in visual studio?

Comment: Since it's not the cell itself that is null but "c.CellValue", you could check inside "c" what are the values inside. You should be able to find the coordinates of the cell.

Comment: You should (always) check whether an object is null before accessing properties or methods of that object. `if(c.CellValue is not null) { text = c.CellValue.Text; ...}`